# Quick Regex Question

Tags: c#, html, regex, url

Could someon please show me a regex which matches everything like: image.php?type=regcheck&`imagehash=3d600fe2ad3c87c9b22ade7e58ef1c48`

this string is contained in a page source..
thanks. :)

edit: here is the place where it is located:

```
<img id="imagereg" src="image.php?type=regcheck&amp;imagehash=3d600fe2ad3c87c9b22ade7e58ef1c48" alt="Registration Image" border="0" height="61" width="201">
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Which engine / envoironment are you using? Do you expect people to do your work?

Comment: 1. Don't parse (X|X?HT)?ML with regex. Use a working parser. If it's worth its salt, it also allows you to scrape the page much easier. 2. Your specifications are non-existent. `.*` matches your example, but it's not what you want. 3. See Lucero.

Comment: what part of the string is variable? what part do you want to save or change?

Comment: i haven't got anything so far, thats the problem. my program is written in c# and no, i don't expexct people to do my work. for someone who works with regex daily this is a 2 minute work, for me it would be a 2 hour work..

Comment: try `image.php\?type=regcheck&imagehash=3d600fe2ad3c87c9b22ade7e58ef1c48` or `.*`

Comment: i want to get everything like the string above as a result. the imagehash is variable.

Comment: Well, you might actually learn something if it takes you 2 hours, so that this is unlikely wasted time. In any case, you have to get sour specification straight (e.g. really know what you want to do) before asking a question - or starting to code.

Comment: Seems to me the `regex` tag reminds people to always include a language/tool tag if they’re looking for a regex that works in just one particular place.  The answer you get for say PHP is going to be a lot different from one for Java, just as one contasting pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hash is the only thing that varies, you replace it with a `.*`, and escape all existing `.` and `?` with `\` since it's a regex special char... so, something like:

```
image\.php\?type=regcheck&imagehash=.*
```

Also note that `.*` can be 'greedy' and take too much of the input - I don't know what you're parsing with regex (some part of the text would help), but maybe a single space after the star would do the trick...

*edit*: Based on your comment, the regex comes down to:

```
"image\.php\?type=regcheck&imagehash=.*"
```

with the `"` belonging *inside* the regex, as in:

```
 string regexExpression = "\"image\.php\?type=regcheck&imagehash=.*\""
```

Comment: here is the text where the image is located:
edit: look at the first post
does this help? :)

Comment: mhm. thanks so far. ;)
but this regex doesn't match anything for me so far.. /:

Comment: Note - his example has the ampersand entity &amp; . This may be the reason for the mismatch.

Comment: yes, you are right. i tried to put the &amp; into the regex, but i still doesn't match anything..

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a parser for that, but since you didn't specify any language, here's a regex to match that.

I'm not sure if you are trying to match the `imagehash` only or the whole string under `src`.

So I will assume, you're trying to match the string under `src`:

```
<img id="imagereg" src="(.*?)" alt="Registration Image" border="0" height="61" width="201">
```

The above regex will match the `src` value with those `alt`, `border`, etc. attributes. But if you want to match **all** `src` values in **all** `img` tags:

```
<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>
```

In Python, you can do a `m = re.search( .. )` and return the group by `m.group(1)`.
In Perl `$source =~ / .. /` return the match group: `$1`

For the ampersand, better to replace it, example in Perl:

```
$string =~ s/&amp;/&/g;
```

Python:

```
string.replace('&amp;', '&')
```

Comment: thank you. :)
but i specified a language - C#
and yes, i don't want to use a parser just for this one match..

Comment: @OmegaVirus: For limited, known HTML  you don’t really need a parser. For such problems a good regex can work great.  It’s only when you start building in all the general contingencies for handling unknown HTML is the tradeoff worth it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't see any `C#` in your question, you might want to re-tag it. :)

Comment: @OmegaVirus, if you want a narrow solution in a specific langauge, you should edit the tags in your question to specify that. I’m thinking you should add both `ʜᴛᴍʟ` and `ᴄ♯`. I’m not sure you really need the `ᴜʀʟ` tag though.